# Lorentz Transformation derivation from minkowski metric

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

I have a question and it's that how can I derive this equation

$$
\Lambda^i_j = \delta_j^i + v^iv_j\frac{\gamma-1}{v^2}
$$

by satisfying the Minkowski metric?

I did it and didn't get what I needed. I also wanted to ask does getting general Lorentz group answer from Minkowski metric automatically derives the following equation?

$$\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda=\eta$$

Comment: $\Lambda$ has 16 components. This is only 9 of them. And it only includes boosts, not rotations.

Comment: By “satisfying minkowski metric” do you mean “leaving the Minkowski metric invariant”?

Comment: yea in a way,But mostly i mean satisfying equation that i just added.

Comment: That is the equation expressing the invariance of the Minkowski metric.

Comment: yes you're right. so how can i leave it invariant?

Comment: And here's the Lorentz transformation in a general direction:$$
 \Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}
  \gamma & \gamma \,\vec{v}^T \\
  \gamma \,\vec{v}^T & I+\frac{\gamma-1}{\vec{v}^2}\,\vec{v}\,\vec{v}^T \\
 \end{bmatrix}\\\\
$$